# OpenMDAO1.x: Feedback a variable for several runs (runlist)

Tags: openmdao

I have two components comp1 and comp2 which form a problem, which should be run several times. To do that I found that I could use the UniformDriver (I don't know if this is the most appropriate one for my purpose). However, I would like to feedback an output from comp2 into comp1. So after the first run, I obtain an output from comp2, which for the next run should be an input to comp1. I think the following example makes it a bit more clear what I would like to do:

```
from openmdao.api import Component, Group, Problem, UniformDriver


class Times2Plus(Component):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Times2Plus, self).__init__()
        self.add_param('x', 1.0)
        self.add_param('z', 2.0)
        self.add_output('y', shape=1)

    def solve_nonlinear(self, params, unknowns, resids):
        unknowns['y'] = params['x'] * 2.0 + params['z']

class Power3(Component):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Power3, self).__init__()
        self.add_param('y', shape=1)
        self.add_output('x', shape=1) # feedback to params['x'] as input in next run

    def solve_nonlinear(self, params, unknowns, resids):
        unknowns['x'] = params['y'] ** 3.0

prob = Problem(root=Group())
prob.driver = UniformDriver(num_samples=5)
prob.root.add('comp1', Times2Plus())
prob.root.add('comp2', Power3())
prob.root.connect('comp1.y', 'comp2.y')
prob.setup()
prob.run()
```

Basically the output x of the component Power3 of the previous run shall be connected to the input x of component Times2Plus. In addition I have some parameter z, which I know beforehand, for component Times2Plus which differs for each run. What would be the best way to include this changing parameter and the feedback option?

Comment: Are you performing a fix point iteration, where you keep running comp1 and comp2 until the values stop changing and the system converges?

Comment: Basically my comp1 wraps some external program to calculate loads for a certain speed and comp2 takes the loads as input to calculate displacements. Now for the next speed, which corresponds to the next run, I would like to feedback the calculated displacements as an input for comp1 to calculate new loads. I know the number of runs, which simpy corresponds to the length of my speed vector, so I do not have to iterate. How can I implement such a structure in OpenMDAO?

Comment: The way you're describing the problem, I suggest using multiple instances of comp1 and comp2, rather than using some kind of drive. You run comp1a, pass its output to comp2a, then pass its output to comp1b, etc.

Comment: Okay, that is of course a solution, but I thought maybe there exists some nicer way to implement it. I guess this is probably quite a unique problem. Thank you for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want a drive in this case. You're talking about a solver (distinct from a driver in OpenMDAO > 1.0).

You can see an example of how to set up this kind of thing in our Sellar Example, using a [Non Linear Gauss Seidel](http://openmdao.readthedocs.org/en/1.4.0/usr-guide/tutorials/sellar.html#building-the-sellar-model). Basically you just need to connect up the components in a circular fashion and then add an appropriate solver to make sure they are converged.

Comment: I see that this is a solution for a mathematical problem, where I am looking for some converged value. However, for my problem as explained in my other comment, I think there is no converged value for which I can solve as I only want to run a fixed number of runs. What would be the right way to implement it for this special problem?